# What is the equivalent of CDW in London?

Tags: untagged

Looking for a vendor to purchase IT equipment (servers/workstations/networking) in London.

CDW has relationships with several big name (and small name) vendors of IT equipment (Cisco, HP, Avaya, IBM, etc.).  They also have sales engineers who are specialized in various IT related departments.  On top of that, we are given a single point of contact for purchases, suggestions, minor consulting, etc.

We are looking for something similar, but based in London/UK since CDW isn't a global company.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are some okay (and some "budget") reseller's in *Nonapeptide*'s list none of them will be able to provide you with pre-sales engineers or consultancy services.

We primarily use [**Insight**](http://uk.insight.com/) for our day-to-day purchases and have done for years. We have a single sales contact, they can source items, suggest alternatives and we've been very happy with them. We've never used them for Professional Services consultancy but I believe they do provide such a service. They also operate in many other regions including the US.

We have also purchased hardware and solutions through the following multi-vendor resellers who can provide good pre-sales tech advice and specification.

- [B2net](http://www.b2net.co.uk/)
- [Kelway (were Repton)](http://www.kelway.co.uk/)

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  This is closer to what I was looking for.  Although Nonapeptide's answers were good as well as we use "budget" vendors for various things (i.e. Dual DVI video cards, keyboards, mice, etc) -we typically use newegg.com for this type of stuff.

Comment: I'd recommend Insight too for what you're wanting, they're not always the cheapest but they have a pretty comprehensive range of hardware, software and services

Answer (score 2):

Here are some suppliers that my UK friends use:

- [ebuyer.co.uk](http://ebuyer.co.uk)
- [dabs.co.uk](http://dabs.co.uk)
- [scan.co.uk](http://scan.co.uk)
- [cpc.co.uk](http://cpc.co.uk)
- [kenable.co.uk](http://kenable.co.uk)
- [comms-express.com](http://comms-express.com)

Comment: Thanks for those links, I've bookmarked them all.  We use various vendors like these in the states.  I also found a site called Bechtle Direct, which seems very similar to CDW (http://www.bechtle.co.uk/).

Comment: I'll bookmark bechtle for myself just in case someone else needs to know about it... or if I move to Jolly Olde England. =)